# Is it possible to show a video or an image in html , with absolute path , when the files are in a disk called E: while localhost's file are in C:?

Tags: html, path, filesystems, video-streaming

I'm trying to create a simple page using `HTML` and `PHP` to show some videos, each video in a separate `videoplayer`.

The problem is that I cannot locate the videos (I have them in a folder in my second HDD called `E:\` ).

I tried using the absolute Windows path

`E://XXXXX/yyyyy/video.mp4`

I looked for a solution, and most of them were about changing the backslash to a normal slash, or escaping the backslash with a double but nothing works.

My `index.php` file is in `C:\Program Files\Ampps\www`

Answer (score 0):

1) You can set a local server for the E: hard drive then use in the html tag.

2) Or as better solution if you have router modem for accessing internet with usb port. You can insert the hdd to the router. Then you can access the ftp on your html file.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQZ9K.png)

[USB settings in modem interface](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/341/)

after enabling ftp server of your hdd on the router, you can set `src="ftp://192.168.1.1/XXXXX/yyyyy/video.mp4"`

192.168.1.1 may be differ as your modem inferface address.